# ajax load shortcode in response

Tags: php, ajax

I have a form in a **page-form.php** file, on Sumbit i need to send the data to **formResult.php** to connect to db and get results (products IDs).
With Ajax in the form.php file i need to load the products IDs in a shortcode like that : **[product id="1, 2, 3"]**.

**form.php** part of getting the result from DB :

```
while( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result) ) {
        echo $row["ID"]; // it does display the IDs in page-form.php
        echo do_shortcode('[product id="'.$row["ID"].'"]'); // if i add this line, nothing is shown ... the problem is here
    }
echo '</div>';
```

**page-form.php** part of getting the result from **form.php**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('#repeater_form').on('submit', function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                url:"/formResult.php",
                method:"POST",
                data:$(this).serialize(),
                success:function(data)
                {
                    $('#success_result').html(data);
                }
            })
        });

    });
```

Comment: Do you have more code? For me everything is good there.

Comment: The shortcode doesnt show in the destination page. If i try to load just the ID it works

Comment: Are you sure  has a valid value? `var_dump($row["ID"]);` in your loop and  `var_dump($result);` before

Comment: Yes the value is correct